WebStorm does not detect tsconfig.*.json files when using extends
I'm using yarn workspaces. Each of of my modules contains a tsconfig.json that extends a root level file. WebStorm previously seemed to be able to follow each file but has suddenly stopped doing so. What setting do I need to change to enable Webstorm to follow my tsconfig file chains?
Example:
/src/my-module/tsconfig


{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.backend.json"
}
  

tsconfig.backend.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsxImportSource": "hono/jsx",
    "resolveJsonModule" : true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}


tsconfig.base.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ESNext",
      "module": "ESNext",
      "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
      "strict": true,
      "lib": ["esnext", "DOM"],
      "types": [ "vite/client", "node"],
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
  "include": ["global.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}  

I've already cleared cache, restarted the TS service, and verified that TypesScript itself (using tsc) doesn't have any issues with the configs.

Apparently WebStorm needs to have these files associated with the TypeScript config file type.
In Settings, Editor > File Types, I needed to add tsconfig.backend.json and tsconfig.base.json to the File name patterns list.

